# Need a tool to convert postgres database to mysql

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I found the mysql migration toolkit which will migrate the tables.But is there something which will  convert the functions as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost certainly not.

If your functions are in the SQL language only, it should probably be doable. But any of the many other languages supported by PostgreSQL (pl/pgsql, perl, python etc) are completely different, and contain much functionality that's simply not supported on MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

There are several data migration tools available on Google to convert database. I use [dbload](http://www.dbload.com) for example.

Answer (score 1):

most likely not. the stored procedure and function language differs greatly between postgresql and mysql. such an application would be costly to develop.